# Xcode 6.3 Can't choose class for my ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, class, storyboard

[image: Connections don't work anymore, because apparently there is not a class like that anymore..]

[image: Before all my custom VC classes were available here in this list, now I can only see the default ones]
This is driving me crazy. I have worked with this xcode iOS project for quite some time now, and now suddenly I see that I can't add my custom View Controller classes to the View Controllers in my storyboard anymore... And the outlets from the classes is not available anymore, I get warnings where I connected the outlets to labels and all that in the storyboard, saying that it is not defined in the custom class... Everything worked before... I have tried to restart xcode and the computer and tried to remove the reference to a custom class and add it again, but I was not able to give a View Controller that subclass anyway...

Any idea what happened?? :(

EDIT: Found this in the Build Phases in Copy bundle Resources. I recently changed from deployment target iOS 8.3 to iOS 7.0.. Something to do with this?

[image: How do I fix this?]

Comment: show an image of the inspector.

Comment: All the subclasses of VC are in Compile sources. However, I found the storyboard and launch screen are red in copy bundle resources. can this be it?

Comment: By adding Engling localization I got the storyboard to stop being red, I removed references and added it to the project again. But I still can't select the VC subclasses...

Answer (score 0):

It is working again after I opened the project again the day after without doing anything special... Just a random bug I guess...